# Why am i unable to extract entitlements from application?

Tags: xcode3.2

I use Xcode 3.2. I built my app to the App Store but I get the error:

```
Warning: Unable to extract entitlements from application: 
/Users/philip/Documents/Untitled/build/Distribution-iphoneos/Untitled.app (-19045)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not using the simulator build.

Comment: I using the device build but still warning: Unable to extract entitlements from application